# Multiple Teradata DDL queries plus a select using Java

Tags: java, jdbc, teradata

May someone help me on that?

I am trying to execute the following query using Java (Teradata JDBC driver):

Connection String:`jdbc:teradata:/xxx.xx.xx.xx/database=XXX,tmode=TERA,charset=UTF8`

JDBC driver:`com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver`

```
BT;
create MULTISET VOLATILE table A as (
   select ...
) WITH DATA  primary index (xxx, xxx) on commit preserve rows;

create MULTISET VOLATILE table B as (
   select ...
) WITH DATA  primary index (xxx, xxx) on commit preserve rows;

create MULTISET VOLATILE table C as (
   select ...
) WITH DATA  primary index (xxx, xxx) on commit preserve rows;

select x.A, x.B, x.C from join A, B, C
ET;
```

But I am getting the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 15.10.00.05] [Error 3932] [SQLState 25000] **Only an ET or null statement is legal after a DDL Statement.**
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDatabaseSQLException(ErrorFactory.java:308)
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.ReceiveInitSubState.action(ReceiveInitSubState.java:109)
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.StatementReceiveState.subStateMachine(StatementReceiveState.java:307)
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.StatementReceiveState.action(StatementReceiveState.java:196)
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.StatementController.runBody(StatementController.java:123)
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.StatementController.run(StatementController.java:114)
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDStatement.executeStatement(TDStatement.java:386)
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDStatement.executeStatement(TDStatement.java:328)
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDStatement.doNonPrepExecuteQuery(TDStatement.java:316)
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDStatement.executeQuery(TDStatement.java:1105)
at dataColector.DataColector.getResultSet(DataColector.java:55)
at CMaestro.getCSVFile(CMaestro.java:1539)
at CMaestro.run(CMaestro.java:125)
at CMaestro.main(CMaestro.java:152)
```

any idea?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Teradata each DDL statement must be committed, there's no way to run multiple `CREATE TABLE` within the same transaction.

You must remove the `BT`/`ET`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had to change the way I was getting the data, I mean, I created one single select with all those joins I needed. Anyway, I appreciate your help.